# Foundation split button to have a close button instead of dropdown?

Tags: css, button, sass, zurb-foundation

I am trying to modify the foundation split button and replace the dropdown icon and functionality with a close icon and functionality. I could do it easily with bootstrap, but cannot figure out how to do it, or if it is even possible with foundation.

Answer (score 0):

This [answer](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/692-control-dropdown-programatically) may help you

With the clic on **id_of_dropdown_list**, your close link

```
Foundation.libs.dropdown.close($('#id_of_dropdown_list'));
```